# How can I make delayed setActivity

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've tried this out but it doesn't really work...
I want it to repeat and to be delayed 500ms
Like H He Hel Hell Hello and repeat

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const c = new Discord.Client();
const token = '';

c.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Logged in.')
    const a = [
        'H',
        'He',
        'Hel',
        'Hell',
        'Hello'
    ]

    let i = 0

    setTimeout(() => {
        c.user.setActivity(a[i])
        i++
    }, 2000);
})

c.login(token)
```

I think this should work... Tell me what i did wrong..

Comment: You mean it will display H.. then after 500ms He and so on and then again repeat from start like H.. then after 500ms He and so on?

Comment: Hey Jack, it works. but it doesnt clear.. maybe some changes??? and my discord 1550#1550.. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`:

```
var timer = setInterval(() => {
    c.user.setActivity(a[i]);
    i++;
    if (i == a.length) clearInterval(timer);
}, 2000);
```

`setTimeout` executes once, `setInterval` executes infinitely (which is why you need the `if` and `clearInterval` with variable reassignment).

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry to necro this post but I found this code really useful and maybe other newbies like me could use it.
attach this to any other active gameobject.

```
public class NAME : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float NAME1 = 3f;
    public GameObject NAME2;

    void Start()
    {
        NAME2.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine(delayactive());
    }

    IEnumerator delayactive()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(add time here and make sure to end with f);
        NAME2.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```